# AngularJS accessing the scope object property inside ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a div with content based on the ngRepeat item and a javascript object. My controller code looks like this,

```
  'use strict';

angular.module('proParApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$location,protocolService) {

        $scope.entryMap = {
            // standard types
            'boolean'       : 'checkbox',         
            'username'      : 'textfield'
        };


        $scope.parameters = [
            {   
                'Name' : 'boolean',
                'Type' : 'boolean'
            }
        ];

  });
```

and i am trying to create my view with

```
     <div data-ng-repeat="parameter in parameters">
            {{parameter.Name}} {{entryMap[ {{parameter.Type}} ]}}
        </div>
```

this does not work. What is the right way to access the entryMap inside the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove interpolation from `parameter.Type`. Using interpolation inside the bracket notation accessor of object will result in invalid syntax. You do not need it when you are already inside interpolation, interpolation directive will automatically get the `parameter.type` evaluated against the scope.

Try:-

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="parameter in parameters">
        {{parameter.Name}} {{entryMap[parameter.Type ]}}
    </div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/R3B3Gb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parameter in parameters">
   {{parameter.Name}} {{entryMap[parameter.Type]}}     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parameter in parameters">
   {{parameter.Name}} {{entryMap[parameter.Type]}}     
</div>
```

You dont need to use `{{` again inside entryMap